# Add jQuery to Custom CQWP to make scrollable - SP2010

Tags: jquery, content-query-web-part, jquery-ui

So if I create a custom cqwp (by that I simply mean customizing the view by adding fields to webpart and modifying the xslt in itemstyle), can I apply jquery after the fact to limit the size the webpart uses on the page, and make all content scrollable?

Basically I made a custom view for cqwp that rolls up blog posts, so it will just list one after another. I want many posts displayed because there are a ton, but the page ends up being very very long this way. So is there some jquery I could apply to this webpart that limits it to a specific size and adds a vertical scroll bar?

Thanks as always with helping a beginner!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. This is done easily by adding the jQuery snippet to the first item the XSLT spews out only.

In your ContentQueryMain.xslt find the template `OuterTemplate.CallItemTemplate`. It has a `<xsl:choose>` going on in it. In the `<xsl:otherwise>` clauss add the following:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="itemstyle">
  <xsl:with-param name="CurPos" select="$CurPosition" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Go to your ItemStyle.xslt and in that either create a new or modify a current template and add this:

```
<xsl:param name="CurPos"/>
```

right under

```
<xsl:template name="MyTemplate" match="Row[@Style='MyTemplate']" mode="itemstyle">
```

So you should have something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="MyTemplate" match="Row[@Style='MyTemplate']" mode="itemstyle">
    <xsl:param name="CurPos"/>
    // Rest of your template structure here
</xsl:template>
```

Within this template add the following:

```
<xsl:if test="$CurPos = 1">
<xsl:comment>
    <![CDATA[
      $(document).ready( function() {
         // your logic to add css etc. to surrounding container here
      });
    ]]>
  </xsl:comment>
</xsl:if>
```

So your end result should be something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="MyTemplate" match="Row[@Style='MyTemplate']" mode="itemstyle">
    <xsl:param name="CurPos"/>
    <xsl:if test="$CurPos = 1">
        <xsl:comment>
            <![CDATA[
              $(document).ready( function() {
                 // your logic to add css etc. to surrounding container here
              });
            ]]>
        </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:if>
    // Rest of your template structure here
</xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes, if you can get the CQWP to output the required HTML for the jquery libraries to operate properly.  If you can't, then you'll have to write something from scratch to do it.